# How to permute all combinations involving both lists, with each element preserved at their respective indices?

Tags: list, scala

I'd like to transform a list to another - for example:

```
val a = List(x,y,z)
val b = List(x1,y1,z1)
```

Desired output

```
List(List(x1,y,z),List(x,y1,z),List(x,y,z1),List(x1,y1,z),
     List(x1,y,z1),List(x,y1,z1),List(x1,y1,z1))
```

The order is to be preserved - hence the built-in combinations function wouldn't be useful. Is there another concise way of doing this with scala?

Comment: The requirement is unclear. Do you want every list made up of two items from one list and one item from the other? If so is the last item in your output a typo?

Comment: What is the logic behind the ordering? If you could define the function that iterates between a and b indices you would be almost done. A bit-wise iteration is simpler. Why is `List(x, y, z)` excluded but `List(x1, y1, z1)` is not?

Comment: It's an n-length list. I'm trying to permute all combinations involving both lists, with each element preserved at their respective indices. List(x,y,z) is implicit, - it can be part of the output if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def permut[A](l: List[(A,A)]): List[List[A]] = l match {
  case Nil => List(List())   // or Nil :: Nil
  case (a,b) :: tail =>
    val t = permut(tail)
    t.map(a :: _) ::: t.map(b :: _)
}

val a = List("x0", "y0", "z0")
val b = List("x1", "y1", "z1")


scala> permut(a zip b)
res22: List[List[String]] = List(List(x0, y0, z0), List(x0, y0, z1), List(x0, y1, z0), List(x0, y1,
z1), List(x1 , y0, z0), List(x1, y0, z1), List(x1, y1, z0), List(x1, y1, z1))
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. Why not just have the `Nil` case return `Nil :: Nil`?

Comment: Cheers Marth, I took the liberty to edit the formatting a bit. I think your solution is good!

Comment: @Marth: Writing code drunk is great! Especially code for Stack Overflow, where you get code review for free.

Answer (score 1):

So, if the order of the permutations is not relevant but only the fact that all appear, it can be solved. The number of permutations is `pow(2, list-length)` or `1 << list-length`. Here is a version:

```
def mix[A](a: Seq[A], b: Seq[A]): IndexedSeq[Seq[A]] = {
  val sz = a.size
  require(sz == b.size, "Sequence lengths do not match")
  (0 until 1 << sz).map { i =>
    (a zip b).zipWithIndex.map { case ((ax, bx), j) =>
      if ((i & 1 << j) == 0) ax else bx
    }
  }
}

val a = List("x0", "y0", "z0")
val b = List("x1", "y1", "z1")

mix(a, b)
```

The outer loop `0 until 1 << sz` iterates over all permutations, e.g. here with lists of length 3, it goes from 0 until 7. The inner loop zips the two input lists along with the running index and then flips between the a and b elements depending on the index. This is done using bit-wise comparison with the outer index.

```
i   1<<j  & == 0
000 001   true  (a)
000 010   true  (a)
000 100   true  (a)

001 001   false (b)
001 010   true  (a)
001 100   true  (a)

010 001   true  (a)
010 010   false (b)
010 100   true  (a)

011 001   false (b)
011 010   false (b)
011 100   true  (a)

etc.
```

Comment: Actually, @Marth's answer is much prettier, the only potential problem being that it is not tail recursive. I tried out to implement it using a recursive list processing function, and came out with basically an identical solution, apart from using `t.flatMap(p => List(a :: p, b :: p))`, which is a minor detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in permutations of Set to calculate and use them as a "belongs to" mask to determine which list should contribute an element to the final combined list.  Using this idea, a possible implementation should be something like this:

```
def xorZip[T](l1:List[T], l2:List[T]):List[List[T]] = {
    def maskedUnzip[T](l:List[((T,T),Int)], mask:Int=>Boolean):List[T] = l.map{ case ((x,y),index) => if (mask(index)) x else y}
    val l1zl2 = l1.zip(l2).zipWithIndex
    val mask = (0 until l1zl2.size).toSet.subsets.toList
    mask.map(mask => maskedUnzip(l1zl2, mask.contains(_)))
  }
```

Scala REPL:

```
scala> val l1 = List("a","b","c")
l1: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val l2 = List("x","y","z")
l2: List[String] = List(x, y, z)

scala> xorZip(l1,l2)
res0: List[List[String]] = List(List(x, y, z), List(a, y, z), List(x, b, z), List(x, y, c), List(a, b, z), List(a, y, c), List(x, b, c), List(a, b, c))
```

Comment: care to explain why down vote? This correctly answers the question at hand.

Comment: I did not down vote, but while it works, it is also quite hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: @0__ Well, the question states 'Is there another concise way of doing this with scala?' which is what I've tried here. There're two keys to understand this implementation. 1) the simple map function `if (mask(index)) x else y` and the other is the built-in `subsets` method of Set [1]. The rest of the code is putting those 2 together with the input lists. Suggestions are welcome. [1] http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set

Comment: I didn't downvote you either, and your solution looks good too! I've accepted the other answer since it felt more elegant. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: In hindsight, your solution is more technically correct - since it preserves the order of lists being produced as well. I love the way you step around the need for recursion. I'd accept your answer, but I don't know if it's SO etiquette to change an accepted answer :) Great job though.